# What does tag 'notes' represent?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, stack-overflow, ambiguous-tags

I saw [notes](/questions/tagged/notes). Somebody uses it to represent [lotus-notes](/questions/tagged/lotus-notes); other put it to represent notes in general.

What is the SO policy on this tag? Is this part of ambiguous general tags? Is this accepted, or it was overlooked?

Comment: If this tag is not worth your use, then it doesnt mean that, nobody needs it. It could be used by some user to represent their issue. _No piece of code is waste_

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj: Hardly. If I tag a question with [tag:something-i-need-to-do] it may mean that _I_ need it, but it's certainly not helpful to anyone else.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I say it is a worthless tag and should be deleted.

However, if this tag is going to be removed (it needs to be done manually), then note the following:

- If it is about Lotus Notes, then it should be tagged [lotus-notes](/questions/tagged/lotus-notes).

  - If it has been tagged  about Lotus Notes, then it need to be checked to see if it is off-topic.  This tag is a very good indicator that the question *might* be off topic.
- If it is *not* about [lotus-notes](/questions/tagged/lotus-notes), then the [notes](/questions/tagged/notes) tag should be removed, and possibly replaced with another tag (if there's an indication it's about a specific technology and the tag was broken in two on the question).

Note (yes, I see the irony here) that when removing [notes](/questions/tagged/notes), I came across the following types of questions:

- Notes on Facebook
- Notes on Tumblr
- Musical notes
- Notes in iOS
- Lotus Notes
- Productivity tools for keeping notes
- Notes in Vim
- Notes in Eclipse

That said, the tag was *way* too vague.

Answer (score 5):

Out of 130 questions using [notes](/questions/tagged/notes), there are:

- [23 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lotus-notes+notes) using [notes](/questions/tagged/notes), and [lotus-notes](/questions/tagged/lotus-notes)
- [54 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lotus+notes) using [notes](/questions/tagged/notes), and [lotus](/questions/tagged/lotus)
- [16 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lotus+notes+lotus-notes) using [notes](/questions/tagged/notes), [lotus](/questions/tagged/lotus), and [lotus-notes](/questions/tagged/lotus-notes)

In the first case, and in the third case, [notes](/questions/tagged/notes) can simply be removed; in the second case the question should be retagged to use [lotus-notes](/questions/tagged/lotus-notes).
After this is done, [notes](/questions/tagged/notes) can be burninated.

Comment: Well, I was going to help out with this, but someone fixed them all in the 28 minutes since you posted.